# How to save audio data recorded using AVAudioRecorder for further use?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Hi i am creating application which can record sound. I can have that recorded sound file and i can play it immediately. I do not know how can I save it on iPhone so that I can play it after reopening application.

Is there any way by which this file will be stored as application save data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say you "have that recorded sound file", how are you storing/using it in your code?  Is it a NSData object or is it some kind of object?

Comment: I take NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath]; and then    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                    initWithURL:soundFileURL
                    settings:recordSettings                                   
                    error:&error];                                      and whenever i play the recorded sound i do                    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                      initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url                                  
                      error:&error];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can do it like this to record it into your documents directory :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFile.ext"];  // Where ext is the audio format extension you have recorded your sound
[yourAudioPlayer.data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```